# problems with modules in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have 2 modules in my application , my virtual host name is myproject

the path of my files are

```
application--modules--default-controllers-index
                                         -error
                                         -authentication

                    --admin  -controllers-users
```

i have some action in my controllers

i could access to every actions in my index controller , but when i want to access the action in my other controller i get error

example , when i access to http://myproject/authentiaction/index

i get this error

Not Found

The requested URL /authentiaction/index was not found on this server.

and this is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your htaccess file

Comment: Do you have an 'authenticaction' module with an index controller?

Comment: no,i have authentication,error,index controllers in my default module and users controller in my admin module

Answer (score 2):

You are basically trying to access the "authentiaction" (sp?) module which does not exist.

Try this:

```
http://myproject/default/authentication/index
```

You can add a default controller directory in your configs/application.ini by adding the following lines:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/default/controllers"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

This should allow you access default controllers without the module in the url.

You could also add a route that directs your url to the default module.

Answer (score 0):

Is this just a typo in your question?

```
/authentiaction/index
```

I assume it should read

```
/authentication/index
```